# Spring Boot + Swagger-Ui yml generate

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi

Create a swagger-ui with the yaml file generated by swagger-editor

Creating an auto swagger-ui using Annotation was successful.

But I do not know how to create Swagger-ui with yaml created with swagger-editor. Is there anyone who can explain in detail? The development environment uses SpringBoot 2.0.4.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    public class SwaggerConfig {

        @Bean
        public Docket getApi() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                    .paths(paths())
                    .build();
        }

        private Predicate<String> paths() {
            return Predicates.and(
                       PathSelectors.regex("/shop.*"),
                       Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")));
        }
    }
```

The above code can make all the APIs inside the server Swagger-ui.
However, I would like to configure swagger-ui with the yaml file that I wrote myself through the swagger-editor.

Comment: Download Swagger-UI distribution and add it as static resource (src/main/resources/static) in your project. Modify the index.html file under dist folder of Swagger-UI to point to your yaml file.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.
Is there a way to automatically manage static resouces? I am wondering how to keep the yaml files in a state where they are located.

Comment: You can keep yaml file like src/main/resources/static/spec/spec_1.0.yaml and change location URL in index.html file under swagger-ui dist to point to localhost:8080/spec/spec_1.0.yaml